# magento: moving files from local to live via FTP

Tags: magento, ftp, localhost, local

I am trying to move my local Magento site to my Live server. (MAMP to cPanel)

To do this I have exported the database, etc and all those steps are fine.

However when I copy my local Magento files from Application/MAMP/htdocs to my FTP client (cyberduck) and choose to overwrite the existing Magento files, to ensure that all my local updates will be moved to the live site, it takes hours to overwrite and then says it has failed!

Does anybody know if I am doing this step correctly, or is there a different way to get my Magento files from my Local site to my Live site.

Comment: OS X being a unix variant will have tar. `tar -czvf filename.tgz` will create a gzipped archive and `tar -xzvf filename.tgz` will uncompress it. It's native to *NIX

Comment: Since you also posted this in the Magento.SE site, I am closing it as off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fast way is to upload a zip file and then unzip this file in your LIVE server if you have shell access.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is this the correct way to do it or is there not one specific way?

Now that I have done this, I am having problems with the rest of the steps to move my site from Local (MAMP) to Live (using cPanel), mainly moving my database from Local to Live, I thought I new how to do it but I don't. I have read so many articles and forums and they are all telling me to do different things! Some say to edit this or edit that and others say delete this or delete that! I don't suppose you could point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: SO your main problem now is to move database to LIVE only? What's the size of DB?

Comment: Yes I need to move my database live! My database is 11.3 MB. Thanks!

Comment: U can do it with phpmyadmin. http://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9143/29/